# BigQuery Error: Cannot parse regular expression

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I don't understand what is wrong with my syntax.

relevant portion of query:

```
COUNTIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(view_context, '$.exit_event'), ''', '') = 'TAP_RIGHT') AS is_view_ctx_tap_right, COUNTIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(view_context, '$.exit_event'), ''', '') = 'TAP_LEFT') AS is_view_ctx_tap_left
```

Error:

```
Cannot parse regular expression: unexpected ): , '') = 'TAP_RIGHT') AS is_view_ctx_tap_right, COUNTIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(view_context, '$.exit_event'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below instead

```
COUNTIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(view_context, '$.exit_event'), "'", '') = 'TAP_RIGHT') AS is_view_ctx_tap_right, 
COUNTIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(view_context, '$.exit_event'), "'", '') = 'TAP_LEFT') AS is_view_ctx_tap_left
```

Note the proposed fix: `"'"` instead of `'''`

Comment: I tried the proposed fix and am now receiving a python error:
`SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

Comment: i answered your original question and most likely your issue in that question is now fixed. The new issue you have is something different and you need (if you want) to post new question with all new relevant details so it can be further addressed. Meantime, I consider this current question is answered, so consider voting up and accept the answer :o)

Comment: btw, meantime try `''''` instead of your current `'''` - this can potentially address conflict in your python code